# How to generate a customized checker board matrix as fast as possible?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need a function that creates a checker board matrix with `M` rows and `N` columns of `P*Q` rectangles. I modified the third solution from [here](http://matlabtricks.com/post-31/three-ways-to-generate-a-checkerboard-matrix) to get that:

```
function [I] = mycheckerboard(M, N, P, Q)
nr = M*P;
nc = N*Q;
i = floor(mod((0:(nc-1))/Q, 2));
j = floor(mod((0:(nr-1))/P, 2))';
r = repmat(i, [nr 1]);
c = repmat(j, [1 nc]);
I = xor(r, c);
```

it works with no problem:

```
I=mycheckerboard(2, 3, 4, 3)

I =
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

But it's not fast enough since there are lots of calls of this function in a single run. Is there a faster way to get the result? How can I remove floating point divisions and/or calls of the `floor` function?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fairly fast for small matrices, but becomes less so as the dimensions get larger. Here's a one-liner using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) (requires Image Processing toolbox that most have):

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
p = 4;
q = 3;

I = imresize(bsxfun(@xor, mod(1:m, 2).', mod(1:n, 2)), [p*m q*n], 'nearest')
```

Or, inspired by @AndrasDeak's use of [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html), this is faster with R2015b:

```
I = kron(bsxfun(@xor, mod(1:m, 2).', mod(1:n, 2)), ones(p, q))
```

For a small bit more speed, the underlying code for `kron` can be simplified by taking advantage of the structure of the problem:

```
A = bsxfun(@xor, mod(1:m, 2).', mod(1:n, 2));
A = permute(A, [3 1 4 2]);
B = ones(q, 1, p);
I = reshape(bsxfun(@times, A, B), [m*n p*q]);
```

or as one (long) line:

```
I = reshape(bsxfun(@times, permute(bsxfun(@xor, mod(1:m, 2).', mod(1:n, 2)), [3 1 4 2]), ones(q, 1, p)), [m*n p*q]);
```

Comment: It would be nice to ditch `kron` altogether, [@Divakar says it's slow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28652280/5067311)...

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Interesting, especially since `kron` itself is just three simple lines of code for full matrices.

Comment: Maybe they are three slow lines;) Anyway, in Divakar's test the overall approaches were different between `kron` and `bsxfun`, so it's possible that not `kron` itself was the bottleneck.

Comment: @saastn if this is not fast enough, then you need to change design. Can you parfor? Is a checkmatrix created more than once, if yes you can hashmap it and just retrieve when needed

Comment: You might try [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) rather than `imresize` or `kron` in 2015a or later. Which I don't have, or I'd post an answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest first creating a binary matrix for the checkerboard's fields, then using the built-in `kron` to blow it up to the necessary size:

```
M = 2;
N = 3;
P = 4;
Q = 3;
[iM,iN] = meshgrid(1:M,1:N);
A = zeros(M,N);
A(mod(iM.'+iN.',2)==1) = 1;
board = kron(A,ones(P,Q))
```