# Matrix which is 1 when row and column are both odd or both even

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a matrix which which has:

- The value 1 if the row is odd and the column is odd
- The value 1 if the row is even and the column is even
- The value 0 Otherwise.

I want to get the same results as the code below, but in a one line (command window) expression:

```
 N=8;
 A = zeros(N);

 for row = 1:1:length(A)
     for column = 1:1:length(A)
        if(mod(row,2) == 1 && mod(column,2) == 1)

             A(row,column*(mod(column,2) == 1)) = 1;

         elseif(mod(row,2)== 0 && mod(column,2) == 0 )

             A(row,column*(mod(column,2) == 0)) = 1;

        end
     end
  end
 disp(A)
```

This is the expected result:

```
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: Your question is a simplification of the one I've marked as a duplicate. Specifically, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35260296/3978545) but in the case that `m=n=N` since your matrix is square, and `p=q=1` since you want cheque squares which are `1*1`.

Comment: @Wolfie, Is it considered a duplication just because the question is a subset of another question? I don't think it's a duplication for the link you gave, because the solution for the question above is much simpler than the general problem.

Comment: @Rotem you say the solution for this question is simpler, but your two solutions are either (1) 3 lines or (2) only valid for even N... The one liner in the dupe is fairly short and sweet, and works for all cases. But you're probably right

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to use implicit expansion of addition, noting that

```
odd+odd = even+even = 0
```

So this is your answer:

```
A = 1 - mod( (1:N) + (1:N).', 2 );
```

---

You could also do this with `toeplitz`, as shown in this [MATLAB Answers Post](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/196631-how-can-i-create-a-matrix-of-alternating-1s-and-0s-for-any-size-matrix)

For a square matrix with number of rows = number of columns = `N`

```
A = toeplitz(mod(1:N,2));
```

If the number of rows (`M`) is not equal to the number of columns (`N`) then

```
A = toeplitz(mod(1:M,2),mod(1:N,2))
```

---

FWIW, you're asking a specific case of this question:

[How to generate a customized checker board matrix as fast as possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260109/how-to-generate-a-customized-checker-board-matrix-as-fast-as-possible/35260296#35260296)

Answer (score 0):

Can you take three lines?

```
N=8;
A = zeros(N);
A(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = 1;
A(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = 1;
```

One line solution (when `N` is even):

```
A = repmat([1, 0; 0 1], [N/2, N/2]);
```

Comment: @MazzEbra, I meat it to be a joke... I was trying to give a quick and simple solution, and came up with 3 lines of code. I had to think a little longer to find a one line solution. I just don't think it's critical.

Comment: @Rotem how about a little extra to yours: A = repmat([1, 0; 0 1], [N, N])(1:N,1:N);

Comment: @Detlf That's not valid MATLAB syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function `meshgrid` to generate mesh grids and use `mod` to determine even or odd

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
A = mod(x+y+1,2);
```

such that

```
>> A
A =

   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```